# Google Sheets/Appscript/Display Date in Specific Cell (C1) when any cell within a range (C1-C50) is edited

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

New to JS (Slowly working my way through), but I've got an issue on a Google Sheet where I'd like to have a date displayed in a specific Cell (C1), when any cell is edited in a range (C2:C50).

Ideally I'm wanting to apply this to multiple ranges (5 - C2:50) but to treat each range individually so that when an edit occurs within each individual range, it will populate the corresponding ranges first row (C2:C50 > Populate C1 etc).

It would be convenient to have it only accept the first edit and not change the value in C1:G1 on further edits, but I'm not sure it's a good idea to implement it this way.

I've tried modifying the below script, but couldn't find the right function to select a specific cell rather than an offset from an individual cell in the range.

Thanks in advance to anyone that can help!

```
/**
* Creates a Date Stamp if a column is edited.
*/

//CORE VARIABLES
// The column you want to check if something is entered.
var COLUMNTOCHECK = 1;
// Where you want the date time stamp offset from the input location. [row, column]
var DATETIMELOCATION = [0,1];
// Sheet you are working on
var SHEETNAME = 'Sheet1'

function onEdit(e) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  //checks that we're on the correct sheet.
  if( sheet.getSheetName() == SHEETNAME ) { 
    var selectedCell = ss.getActiveCell();
    //checks the column to ensure it is on the one we want to cause the date to appear.
    if( selectedCell.getColumn() == COLUMNTOCHECK) { 
      var dateTimeCell = selectedCell.offset(DATETIMELOCATION[0],DATETIMELOCATION[1]);
      dateTimeCell.setValue(new Date());
      }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe your goal is as follows.

- When the cells "C2:C50" are edited, you want to put the value of `new Date()` to the cell "C1".
- You want to use `onEdit` simple trigger.

In this case, how about the following modified script?

#### Modified script:

Please copy and paste the following script to the script editor of Spreadsheet and save the script. When you use this script, please edit the cells "C2:C50" of "Sheet1". By this, the script is automatically run by the simple trigger of `onEdit`. By this, `new Date()` is put to the cell "C1".

```js
function onEdit(e) {
  var COLUMNTOCHECK = 3;
  var SHEETNAME = 'Sheet1';

  var range = e.range;
  var sheet = range.getSheet();
  if (sheet.getSheetName() != SHEETNAME || range.columnStart != COLUMNTOCHECK || range.rowStart < 2 || range.rowStart > 50) return;
  sheet.getRange("C1").setValue(new Date());
}
```

#### Note:

- This script is run by `onEdit` trigger. So when you directly run this script with the script editor, an error like `TypeError: Cannot read property 'range' of undefined` occurs. Please be careful about this. When you use this script, please edit the cells "C2:C50" of "Sheet1".

#### References:

- [Simple Triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers)
- [Event Objects](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events)

### Added:

About the following new question,

> If I wanted to apply this to several columns, how would I do this?

The sample script is as follows.

#### Sample script:

Please set the column numbers you want to use to `var COLUMNTOCHECK = [3, 4, 5];`.

```js
function onEdit(e) {
  var COLUMNTOCHECK = [3, 4, 5]; // 3, 4, 5 are corresponding to columns "C", "D" and "E".
  var SHEETNAME = 'Sheet1';

  var range = e.range;
  var sheet = range.getSheet();
  var col = range.columnStart;
  if (sheet.getSheetName() != SHEETNAME || !COLUMNTOCHECK.includes(col) || range.rowStart < 2 || range.rowStart > 50) return;
  sheet.getRange(1, col).setValue(new Date());
}
```

- In this case, the value of `new Date()` is put to the 1st row of each column. If you always want to put it to the cell "C1", please modify `getRange(1, col)` to `getRange("C1")`.

Comment: @scrappynmap Thank you for replying. Now, I noticed your reply. I apologize for this. From `Thank you! Worked like a charm.`, I understood that your question was resolved. I'm glad for it. And about your new question of `If I wanted to apply this to several columns, how would I do this?`, I added one more sample script in my answer. Could you please confirm it?